# How to place a container (two rows) inside with two containers (in two different rows) in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

How to place a container (two rows) with two containers (in two different rows) in bootstrap?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBsIf.png)

i want containers arranged like this

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt e.g. as a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), so we can try to solve your problem and explain why your own attempt failed - that way you can learn something useful for your future development, as well as getting an answer to this single problem.

Comment: attached a sample image

Comment: i want containers arranged like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      .gray{border:5px solid gray;
        height: 100px;


      }
      .green{border: 5px solid green;
        height: 300px;
     }

        .orange{
          border: 5px solid orange;
          height: 350px;

        }

         .greenplus{border: 5px solid green;
        height: 50px;
       }
    </style>
    <body>
      <div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;">
        <div class="row" >
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
            <div class="row"  style="padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;">
              <div class="gray"></div>
             <br>
               <div class="green"></div>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="row" style="padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;">
               <div class="orange"></div>
               <br>
               <div class="greenplus"></div>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use grid to do these kind of things.
Can you Illustrate what should it look like?(I could help you more then)

EDIT:
For this you actually need just a row with two columns.

And it will look like this:

```
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-8">  <!-- 8 is the width of the left side -->

        You content here

      </div>

     <div class="col-md-4">  <!-- 4 is the width of the right side -->

        Your content here

      </div>

    </div>
```

If you need so that the content inside of those columns is also a grid, then it will be a bit different:

```
   <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-8">  <!-- 8 is the width of the left side -->

       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12"></div>
          <!-- You just add your columns here -->
       </div>

       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12"></div>
          <!-- You just add your columns here -->
       </div>

      </div>

     <div class="col-md-4">  <!-- 4 is the width of the right side -->

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12"></div>
          <!-- You just add your columns here -->
       </div>

       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12"></div>
          <!-- You just add your columns here -->
       </div>

      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: look at the attached image once

Comment: you are not getting, what i want to ask

Comment: @RISHABHBANSAL Can you please explain more then?

Comment: Sir, i have explained with the help of the attached image. I want division like this. So that i can use them to write my content

Comment: @RISHABHBANSAL Is there a website having this kind of arrangement or something? I just don't understand what exactly you need.
Are those 4 seperate containers in two columns or are there just 2 containers in 2 columns?